# .htaccess https redirect failing

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have setup an SSL certificate on a domain I am testing with and the SSL works you can see here: https://naughtyrobot.co.uk/ - I also verified my domain has a valid SSL certificate here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=naughtyrobot.co.uk

I have created a .htaccess file in the root directory and it looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:SSL} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.naughtyrobot\.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) https://naughtyrobot.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I checked to ensure the root is correct by looking at: `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

But if you visit [naughtyrobot.co.uk](http://naughtyrobot.co.uk) it just seems to route to the standard `http://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://naughtyrobot.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```